# Exception on using Double.valueOf() method

Tags: java, android, exception, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in Android development. I am making a basic square equations solver. 
I use the code below to get strings from `EditText` elements:

```
a = mA.getText().toString(); 
b = mB.getText().toString(); 
c = mC.getText().toString();
```

Then I use `Double.valueOf()` method to convert them into doubles and solve the equatation(`s` is a Solver instance):

```
mSolution.setText(s.solve(Double.valueOf(a),
                       Double.valueOf(b), Double.valueOf(c)));
```

If `EditText` is empty, an attempt to solve it gives me an exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

I guess, the `.toString()` method returns `null` or `""`, but the if statement doesn't work here :c.

Comment: Show your if statement please.

Comment: Why doesn't the if statement work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check Strings with `equals` like

```
if(!"".equals(mB.getText().toString()))
   //then your if statement
```

Comment: mistakes happens ;) you are wellcome.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you catch that Exception?

```
try{
    mSolution.setText(s.solve(Double.valueOf(a),Double.valueOf(b), Double.valueOf(c)));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //whatever you feel necessary to do when en empty string is presented
}
```

Advantage: You don't have to check every String for its correctness.
Disadvantage: You dont know which String is not correct.
BUT: You could for example insert Arashs code in the catch, so that at that point you can check which string is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

You got `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""` because you trying to convert **NULL** value into **Double**

so before convert this value you must check the **String** is null or not like below:

```
 if(!a.equals("") && !b.equals("") && !c.equals("")){
  //Do your job
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {

        if (a != null && a.length != 0 && b != null && b.length != 0
                && b != null && b.length != 0) {
            mSolution.setText(s.solve(Double.valueOf(a), Double.valueOf(b),
                    Double.valueOf(c)));
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""` because the values of `a',`b`, or`c` is sometime empty i.e "".

`Double.valueOf()` will return `NumberFormatException` if it is empty. To avoid this you can give check points like below,

```
if(mA.getText().toString().equals("") ||mB.getText().toString().equals("")||mC.getText().toString().equals("") )
   {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edittext is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   else
    {
      a = mA.getText().toString(); 
      b = mB.getText().toString(); 
      c = mC.getText().toString();
    }
```